# Sharing the same host var in ansible inventory

Tags: ansible, ansible-inventory

I'm looking for a correct way to construct an inventory to share the same var.

Here is my inventory

```
{
    "groupA": {
        "hosts": [
            "192.168.1.1"
        ]
    },
    "groupB": {
        "hosts": [
            "192.168.1.2"
        ]
    },
    "vars": {
        "ansible_ssh_user": "admin",
        "ansible_ssh_private_key_file": "/admin.pem",
        "ansible_become": "yes",
        "ansible_become_method": "sudo"
    }
}
```

I want both **groupA** and **groupB** to use the same var declared.

Moreover, how can I specify in playbook to run both **groupA** and **groupB**. The following one seems not to work

```
hosts: groupA, groupB
```

[**UPDATE**] Below is the correct construct after getting support from [Konstantin Suvorov](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2795592/konstantin-suvorov).

```
{
    "groupA": {
        "hosts": [
            "192.168.1.1"
        ]
    },
    "groupB":{
        "hosts":[
            "192.168.1.2"
        ]
    },
    "root":{
        "children":[
            "groupA",
            "groupB"
        ],
        "vars": {
            "ansible_ssh_user": "admin"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Drop your vars into some dummy group that is parent to both groups:

```
  "root": {
    "children": ["groupA", "groupB"],
    "vars": {
        "ansible_ssh_user": "admin"
    }
  },
```

Correct pattern is `hosts: groupA:groupB` or `hosts: group[AB]`

Comment: Thank you for your prompt support. It worked like a charm! I updated in my question to share with others.

Comment: don't user name `groups` as group name – it's a reserved word, you can get unpredictable results.